# laravel create wont store first row of data array

Tags: php, laravel

I have select options in my form where it has first row when page loads and users can add more rows by AJAX and store all rows data at once.

The problem is that my first row (which is visible when page loads) does not save the data while all other added rows will be saved.

Here is a screenshot of my select options when page loads:

[image: selected options]

And here it is when user adds new rows:

[image: explanation of visual interaction]

Here is my sample data that those rows have sent to controller (screenshot #2):

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "ali"
    "username" => "alireza"
    "action" => "delete"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "eraty"
    "username" => "aery"
    "action" => "optional"
  ]
]
```

As I explained in my screenshots, object 0 data will not be store in the database, not sure why.

Here is my controller:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'note' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $post = Post::where('id', $id)
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->first();

    $post->user_id = Auth::id();
    $post->note = $request->input('note');

    if ($post->save()) {
        // social media  (add new)
        $socialHeir = $request->input('social_media_heir');
        $socialAction = $request->input('social_media_action');
        $socialNames = $request->input('social_media_name');
        $socialUsernames = $request->input('social_media_username');
        if (!empty($socialNames)) {
            $result_array = [];
            foreach ($socialNames as $key => $val) {
                $result_array[$key] = [
                    'name' => $socialNames[$key],
                    'username' => $socialUsernames[$key],
                    'action' => $socialAction[$key]
                ];
            }

            // dd($result_array); <-- result of this line I shared above (after screenshot 2)

            foreach ($result_array as $key => $merge) {
                if (!empty($key) && !empty($merge)) {
                    SocialMedia::create([
                        'owner_id' => Auth::id(),
                        'heir_id' => $socialHeir,
                        'post_id' => $post->id,
                        'name' => $merge['name'],
                        'username' => $merge['username'],
                        'what_to_do' => $merge['action'],
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return redirect()->route('posts.index');
}
```

---

### Update

`SocialMedia` model:

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'owner_id',
    'heir_id',
    'post_id',
    'name',
    'username',
    'what_to_do',
];

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

`Post` model

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'note',
];

public function socialMedias()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SocialMedia::class);
}
```

Comment: Please check the fillable property in your model.

Comment: Put your model file code `SocialMedia` and `Post` model code

Comment: have you passed `protected $table = 'table';` in model ??

Comment: yes, both of them

Comment: Okay try below answer wise condition after save record of post

Comment: Your error makes no sense... you did not click the `+` to add the row, why would that row then be saved ? Also, avoid the `if guard`, like [here](https://engineering.helpscout.com/reducing-complexity-with-guard-clauses-in-php-and-javascript-74600fd865c7) or [here](https://codeinphp.github.io/post/replace-nested-conditions-with-guard-clauses/)...

Comment: I solved it already, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The issue was in `$key` in my foreach after removing it, it saves all rows now.

```
foreach($result_array as $merge) {
    if(!empty($merge)) {
        SocialMedia::create([
            'owner_id' => Auth::id(),
            'heir_id' => $socialHeir,
            'post_id' => $will->id,
            'name' => $merge['name'],
            'username' => $merge['username'],
            'what_to_do' => $merge['action'],
        ]);
    }
}
```